# change background of a div containing divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sure the answer is really simple, but I can't figure this out :

http://jsfiddle.net/VfQAH/

I have a bunch of divs in a table style layout like so :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col boxname">Box Name</div>
    <div class="col length">Length</div>
    <div class="col width">Width</div>
    <div class="col height">Height</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col boxname">A</div>
    <div class="col length">1</div>
    <div class="col width">2</div>
    <div class="col height">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col boxname">B</div>
    <div class="col length">1</div>
    <div class="col width">2</div>
    <div class="col height">3</div>
</div>
```

I want rows to change color on hover, for that I have :

```
.row :hover{
    background: #003366;
}
```

But the background changes only on the hovered cell, instead of the whole row. 
Do I have to use JS to make it happen like I want, or is there a simple CSS trick that I don't know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use `.row:hover` instead of `.row :hover` to highlight the whole row.

```
.row:hover{
    background: #003366;
}
```

Your original selector, `.row hover`, selects all hovered elements which **descend** from `.row`, instead of `.row` itself.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/VfQAH/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the space

```
.row:hover{
  background: #003366;
}
```

Otherwise it is interpreted as

```
.row *:hover{
  background: #003366;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/VfQAH/1/)